# Gitlab CI/CD Pass artifacts/variables between pipelines

Tags: gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, pass-data

## tl;dr

How do I pass data, e.g. the `$BUILD_VERSION` variable, between jobs in different pipelines in Gitlab CI?

So (in my case) this:

```
Pipeline 1 on push ect.            Pipeline 2 after merge

    `building` job ...                `deploying` job
          │                                ▲
          └─────── $BUILD_VERSION ─────────┘
```

---

## Background

Consider the following example (full `yml` below):

```yaml
building:
    stage: staging
    # only on merge requests
    rules:
        # execute when a merge request is open
        - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
          when: always
        - when: never
    script:
        - echo "BUILD_VERSION=1.2.3" > build.env
    artifacts:
        reports:
            dotenv: build.env

deploying:
    stage: deploy
    # after merge request is merged
    rules:
        # execute when a branch was merged to staging
        - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $STAGING_BRANCH
          when: always
        - when: never
    dependencies: 
        - building
    script:
        - echo $BUILD_VERSION
```

I have two stages, *staging* and *deploy*. The `building` job in *staging* builds the app and creates a "Review App" (no separate build stage for simplicity). The `deploying` job in *deploy* then uploads the new app.

The pipeline containing the `building` job runs whenever a merge request is opened. This way the app is built and the developer can click on the "Review App" icon in the merge request. The `deploying` job is run right after the merge request is merged. The idea is the following:

```
                      *staging* stage (pipeline 1)        *deploy* stage (pipeline 2)

<open merge request> -> `building` job (and show)   ...   <merge> -> `deploying` job
                             │                                            ▲
                             └───────────── $BUILD_VERSION ───────────────┘
```

The problem for me is, that the *staging*/`building` creates some data, e.g. a `$BUILD_VERSION`. I want to have this `$BUILD_VERSION` in the *deploy*/`deploying`, e.g. for creating a new release via the Gitlab API.

So my question is: How do I pass the `$BUILD_VERSION` (and other data) from *staging*/`building` to *deploy*/`deploying`?

---

## What I've tried so far

### `artifacts.reports.dotenv`

The described case is more less handled in the gitlab docs in [Pass an environment variable to another job](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#pass-an-environment-variable-to-another-job). Also the `yml` file shown below is heavily inspired by this example. Still, it does not work.

The `build.env` artifact is created in `building`, but whenever the `deploying` job is executed, the `build.env` file gets removed as shown below in line 15: "Removing build.env". I tried to add `build.env` to the `.gitignore` but it still gets removed.

[image: Preparing environment - Running on runner- via gitlab-runner... - Getting source from Git repository - Fetching changes with git depth set to 50... - Reinitialized existing Git repository in - Checking out as staging... - Removing build.env - Skipping Git submodules setup - Executing "step_script" stage of the job script - Using docker image - echo $BUILD_VERSION - Job succeeded]

After hours of searching I found in [this gitlab issue comment](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/246777#note_417210007) and [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65878853/5934316) that the `artifacts.reports.dotenv` doesn't work with the `dependencies` or the `needs` keywords.

Removing `dependencies` doesn't work. Using `needs` only doesn't work either. Using both is not allowed.

Does anyone know a way how to get this to work? I feel like this is the way it should work.

### Getting the artifacts as a file

This answer of the stackoverflow post [Gitlab ci cd removes artifact for merge requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65878853/5934316) suggests to use the `build.env` as a normal file. I also tried this. The (relevant) `yml` is the following:

```yaml
building:
    # ...
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - build.env

deploying:
    # ...
    before_script:
        - source build.env
```

The result is the same as above. The `build.env` gets removed. Then the `source build.env` command fails because `build.env` does not exist. (Doesn't matter if `build.env` is in the `.gitignore` or not, tested both)

### Getting the artifacts from the API

I also found the answer of the stackoverflow post [Use artifacts from merge request job in GitLab CI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66344557/5934316) which suggests to use the API together with `$CI_JOB_TOKEN`. But since I need the artifacts in a non-merge-request pipeline, I cannot use the suggested `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_REF_PATH`.

I tried to use `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME`. The (important section of the) `yml` is then:

```yaml
deploying:
    # ...
    script:
        - url=$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/jobs/artifacts/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME/download?job=building
        - echo "Downloading $url"
        - 'curl --header "JOB-TOKEN: ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" --output $url'
        # ...
```

But this the API request gets rejected with "404 Not Found". Since [commit SHAs are not supported](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#download-a-single-artifact-file-from-specific-tag-or-branch), `$CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA` or `$CI_COMMIT_SHA` do not work either.

### Using `needs`

*Update*: I found the section [Artifact downloads between pipelines in the same project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifact-downloads-between-pipelines-in-the-same-project) in the gitlab docs which is exactly what I want. But: I can't get it to work.

The `yml` looks like the following after more less copying from the docs:

```yaml
building:
    # ...
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - version
        expire_in: never

deploying:
    # ...
    needs:
        - project: $CI_PROJECT_PATH
          job: building
          ref: staging # building runs on staging branch, main doesn't work either
          artifacts: true
```

Now the `deploying` job instantly fails and I get the following error banner:

[image: This job depends on other jobs with expired/erased artifacts: Please refer to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#dependencies]

I tried to set `artifacts.expire_in = never` (as shown) but I still get the same error. Also in *Settings* > *CI/CD* > *Artifacts* "Keep artifacts from most recent successful jobs" is selected. So the artifact should be present. What did I miss here? This should work according to the docs!

---

I hope somebody can help me on getting the `$BUILD_VERSION` to the `deploying` job. If there are other ways than the ones I've tried, I'm very happy to hear them. Thanks in advance.

---

The example `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
stages:
    - staging
    - deploy

building:
    tags: 
        - docker
    image: bash
    stage: staging
    rules:
        - if: ($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event") && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "staging"
          when: always
        - when: never
    script:
        - echo "BUILD_VERSION=1.2.3" > build.env
    artifacts:
        reports:
            dotenv: build.env
    environment:
        name: Example
        url: https://example.com

deploying:
    tags: 
        - docker
    image: bash
    stage: deploy
    rules:
        - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "staging"
          when: always
        - when: never
    dependencies:
        - building
    script:
        echo $BUILD_VERSION
```

Comment: artifacts/dependencies should work.  Get rid of `reports: dotenv:` and do `paths:` instead.  Then keep `dependencies:` exactly as you have it to restore build.env in the deploy pipeline

Comment: @Peter Sadly this doesn't work. Again I get "Removing build.env" as shown in the screenshot. I copied the `yml` from my answer and changed only the `artifacts.reports` of `building` to `artifacts.paths: -build.env`

Comment: Sorry, missed the part where you were trying to skip the `building` stage on some builds, and trying to pass the data between unrelated pipelines.  See my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use CI/CD to pass artifacts between entirely unrelated pipelines.  The fact that "building" is run on the branch that defines merge request, and "deploying" is run on the result of the merge, doesn't imply that "deploying" is just the next stage.  What if another MR was merged in between?  What if there were merge conflicts?

In other words, you can't skip "building" on the main branch just because you built the development branch.  Let "building" happen all the time, and limit "deploy" to main branch.  In this setup, you can easily pass artifacts from "building" to "deploy".

Alternatively, if you want the merge event to actually update the main branch with the version state, just use a source-controlled VERSION file.  That's what git is for.  When you merge, main will take on the VERSION from the branch.  If a different branch got in first, you'll have to resolve the conflict, as you should.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess this is the answer of my question: "It doesn't work". Even though that's not what I wanted to hear. Is there a way to make the pipelines "related"? I assumed that they already are related considering the commit history. One pipeline runs on (one of) the parent commit, the next one on the following commit.

Comment: How about storing the artifacts under the git log checksum (`git log | md5sum`). If you then run the deploy pipeline on your main/master branch, it could generate the git log checksum and try to fetch artifacts. If they exist, use them. If they do not exist, run the build steps.

Answer (score 9):

Going by the Gitlab docs, it should be possible to download any job's artifact by URL, if it hasn't expired yet.

In addition, you can use the Gitlab API to download (unexpired) artifacts from other projects, too; and you can use the Gitlab API to mark a job's artifacts for keeping-regardless-of-expiry-policy, or to delete an artifact.

But I have not tried this myself.

For your case, assuming the 'building' and 'deploying' jobs both run on the `main` branch, you can hopefully pass the artifact like so.

If you have some other way of finding out in the `deploying` job what branch name X the `building` job ran on, then you can download the artefact from branch X instead of always from `main` like I do below.

```yaml
# Assuming
# domain: example.com
# namespace: mygroup
# project: myproject

building:
    # on latest commit on `main`, because we need a predictable
    # branch name to save/retrieve the artifact.
    stage: staging
    script:
        - echo "BUILD_VERSION=1.2.3" > build.env
    artifacts:
        # 'paths', not 'reports'
        paths:
            - build.env

deploying:
    # after merge request is merged
    stage: deploy
    dependencies: 
        - building
    script:
        # could use ${CI_PROJECT_URL} to get https://example.com/mygroup/myproj
        - curl https://${CI_SERVER_HOST}/${CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE}/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}/-/jobs/artifacts/main/raw/build.env?job=building > build.env
        - source build.env
        - echo $BUILD_VERSION  # should print '1.2.3'.
```

The relevant parts of the docs, with links and excerpts:

#### [Access a branch or tag's latest job artifacts by URL](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#access-the-latest-job-artifacts-by-url)

To browse or download the latest artifacts of a branch, use one of these two urls. [I think the `/file/` variant is used for Gitlab Pages artifacts, but I'm not sure. --Esteis]

- Browse artifacts:
  `https://example.com/<namespace>/<project>/-/jobs/artifacts/<ref>/browse?job=<job_name>`
- Download zip of all artifacts:
  `https://example.com/<namespace>/<project>/-/jobs/artifacts/<ref>/download?job=<job_name>`
- Download one artifact file:
  `https://example.com/<namespace>/<project>/-/jobs/artifacts/<ref>/raw/<path/to/file>?job=<job_name>`
- Download one artifact file (Gitlab Pages-related?):
  `https://example.com/<namespace>/<project>/-/jobs/artifacts/<ref>/file/<path>?job=<job_name>`

For example, to download an artifact with domain `gitlab.com`, namespace `gitlab-org`, project `gitlab`, latest commit on `main` branch, job `coverage`, file path `review/index.html`:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/jobs/artifacts/main/raw/review/index.html?job=coverage

#### [Config setting: Keep artifacts from each branch's most recent succesful jobs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#keep-artifacts-from-most-recent-successful-jobs)

- This option is on by default
- [AFAICT](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/16267) it keeps the most recent artifact for

  - every active branch or tag (a.k.a. a 'ref');
  - if multiple pipelines are run on that ref, last pipeline's artifacts overwrite those produced by earlier pipelines.
- All other artifacts are still governed by the `expire_in` setting in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` that produced them.

#### [Gitlab API for job artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html)

Advantage of using the Gitlab API is that if you can get the right tokens, you can also download artifacts from other projects. You'll need the numeric project ID -- that's $CI_PROJECT_ID, if your script is running in Gitlab CI.

To download an artifact archive:

- `curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/jobs/artifacts/main/download?job=test"`

To download a single artifact file:

- `curl --location --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/jobs/artifacts/main/raw/some/release/file.pdf?job=pdf"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did try this some time ago but I didn't get it to work. The API needs the job id of the previous job and I had big troubles finding it. There might be a way to get the last run job of a given branch, but I don't remember. I solved my problem already by tagging commits (tags can be pulled and therefore are easy to get)

Comment: Yeah, manually tagging commits is probably the easiest way to get this working. This answer's final API urls look like they auto-resolve to the last-run job of a given branch, perhaps they could still work? Once I'm messing with Gitlab again I'll try it out. Ditto my other answer below: untested, but might work, and the research so far might save somebody some work. If I get around to testing in the future, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Please provide a tested solution, rather than your theory based on reading the docs.

Answer (score 4):

I assume we start out knowing the commit hash whose artifacts we want to retrieve.

This is the plan:

`commit hash --> job id --> artifact archive --> extract artifact`

1. Gitlab's GraphQL API makes it possible to get, in JSON, a list of jobs for a project + artifact urls for each job.
2. You can filter that JSON list for the commit + jobname you want. Can't do it in GraphQL directly, so I'm doing it in Python.
3. Then print either the job id or the artifact archive url. In our case, we're grabbing the artifact archive URL directly; but somebody else might want to use the job id as input for some other API call.

#### First, let's look at just the GraphQL query and its result, to get a feel for the data available

##### GraphQL query: project jobs and artifacts

Here's the query to get a list of jobs for a project. You can try it out by pasting it into [Gitlab's GraphQL explorer](https://gitlab.com/-/graphql-explorer).

```js
query {
  # FIXME: your project path goes here
  project(fullPath: "gitlab-org/gitlab") {
    # First page of jobs. To get the next page, change the head to
    # jobs(after: "123_my_endCursor") { ... }
    # You can find the endCursor in pageInfo
    jobs {
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        startCursor
      }
      # No, we can't filter on `nodes(name: "my-job-name")`,
      # nor on `edges{ node(name: "my-job-name") }`. :-(
      nodes {
        id
        name
        commitPath
        artifacts {
          edges {
            node {
              downloadPath
              fileType
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

##### GraphQL result

The GraphQL API will return JSON that looks like below. It contains cursor names for pagination, and a list of jobs. In this example the first job has no artifact, the second job does. In practice this list will contain 100 jobs.

```js
{
  "data": {
    "project": {
      "jobs": {
        "pageInfo": {
          "endCursor": "eyJpZCI6IjE1NDExMjgwNDAifQ",
          "startCursor": "eyJpZCI6IjE1NDExNTY0NzEifQ"
        },
        "nodes": [
          {
            "id": "gid://gitlab/Ci::Build/1541156471",
            "name": "review-docs-cleanup",
            "refName": "refs/merge-requests/67466/merge",
            "refPath": "/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/commits/refs/merge-requests/67466/merge",
            "commitPath": "/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/commit/5ec616f5e8f3268c23ff06dc52ef098f76352a7f",
            "artifacts": {
              "edges": []
            }
          },
          {
            "id": "gid://gitlab/Ci::Build/1541128174",
            "name": "static-analysis 4/4",
            "refName": "refs/merge-requests/67509/merge",
            "refPath": "/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/commits/refs/merge-requests/67509/merge",
            "commitPath": "/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/commit/41f949d3a398968edb67e22526c93c2f5292c23d",
            "artifacts": {
              "edges": [
                {
                  "node": {
                    "downloadPath": "/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/jobs/1541128174/artifacts/download?file_type=metadata",
                    "fileType": "METADATA"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "node": {
                    "downloadPath": "/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/jobs/1541128174/artifacts/download?file_type=archive",
                    "fileType": "ARCHIVE"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Code that would hopefully work in practice

Please take care, the scripts below

- Do not handle pagination
- Have not been run from inside a CI container

  - The initial GraphQL API request script is untested
  - The final command to download and extract the archive is untested
  - Only the JSON -> path part has been tested. That bit works for sure.

##### `get-jobs-as-json.sh`: (token, project name) --> joblist

```js
#!/bin/sh

# Usage:
#
#   GRAPHQL_TOKEN=mysecret get-jobs-as-json.sh gitlab-org/gitlab
#
# You can authorize your request by generating a personal access token to use
# as a bearer token.
# https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html

main() {
    # We want curl to see ` \" `, so we type ` \\\" ` when we define $QUERY.
    # I type        : \\\"$group_and_project\\\"
    # QUERY contains: \"asdf/jkl\"
    # I type        : --data "{\"query\": \"$QUERY\"}
    # Curl sees     : '{"query": "...\"asdf/jkl\"...}"
    group_and_project="$1"
    QUERY="
      query {
        # Project path goes here
        project(fullPath: \\\"$group_and_project\\\") {

          # First page of jobs. To get the next page, change the head to
          # jobs(after: \\\"123_my_endCursor\\\") { ... }
          # You can find the endCursor in pageInfo
          jobs {
            pageInfo {
              endCursor
              startCursor
            }
            # No, you can't filter on nodes(name: \\\"my-job-name\\\"),
            # nor on edges{ node(name: \\\"my-job-name\\\") }.
            nodes {
              id
              name
              refName
              refPath
              commitPath
              artifacts {
                edges {
                  node {
                    downloadPath
                    fileType
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    "
    curl "https://gitlab.com/api/graphql"
        --header "Authorization: Bearer $GRAPHQL_TOKEN" \
        --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
        --request POST \
        --data "{\"query\": \"$QUERY\"}"
}

main "$1"
```

##### `json2jobinfo.py`: (joblist, job name, commit SHA) --> (slug of) archive url

Here is a Python script that will read the joblist JSON from stdin, and print the artifact archive path of the job + commit combination you specify.

```js
#!/usr/bin/python3

# json2jobinfo.py

"""Read JSON from stdin, print archive path of job with correct (jobname, commit) combo.

The commit SHA does not have to be the full hash, just the start is enough.

Usage:
    json2jobinfo.py JOBNAME GITHASH

Example:
    json2jobinfo.py 'static-analysis 4/4' 41f949
    json2jobinfo.py 'static-analysis 4/4' 41f949d3a398968edb67e22526c93c2f5292c23d
"""


import sys, json
from pprint import pprint
from typing import List, Dict, Tuple


def matches_sha(commitPath: str, pattern: str) -> bool:
    """True if this commitPath's commit hash starts with {pattern}"""
    commit_part = commitPath.split('/')[-1]
    # print(commit_part)
    # print(pattern)
    return commit_part.startswith(pattern)


def filter_commit_job(jobs: List[Dict], jobname: str, commit: str) -> List[Dict]:
    """Given list of job dicts, find job with correct jobname and commit SHA"""
    return [
        j for j in jobs
        if matches_sha(j['commitPath'], commit)
        and j['name'] == jobname
    ]


def get_archive_url(job: Dict) -> str:
    """Given job dict, return download path of 'ARCHIVE' artifact"""
    archive = [
        arti for arti in job['artifacts']['edges']
        if arti['node']['fileType'] == 'ARCHIVE'
    ][0]
    return archive['node']['downloadPath']


def main_sans_io(graphql_reply: str, jobname: str, commit: str) -> Tuple[str, str]:
    """Return job id, artifact archive download path"""
    jobs = json.loads(graphql_reply)['data']['project']['jobs']['nodes']
    job = filter_commit_job(jobs, jobname, commit)[0]
    job_id = job['id'].split('/')[-1]
    archive_url = get_archive_url(job)
    return job_id, archive_url


def main(args):
    """Read stdin; look for job with correct jobname and commit; print
    download path of artifacts archive"""
    if len(args) == 3:
        jobname, commit = args[1], args[2]
    else:
        # hardcoded for example purposes
        jobname = 'static-analysis 4/4'
        commit = '41f949d3a398968edb67e22526c93c2f5292c23d'

    graphql_reply = sys.stdin.read()
    job_id, job_archive_url = main_sans_io(graphql_reply, jobname, commit)
    print(job_archive_url)

    # If you want to see the json, instead:
    # pprint(job)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

#### Combined usage:

```
# First, ensure $GRAPHQL_TOKEN contains your personal access token

# Save current directory
oldpwd=$(pwd)

# cd to a temporary directory
cd $(mktemp -d)

zip_path=$( \
    ./get-jobs-as-json.sh gitlab-org/gitlab \
    | ./json2jobinfo.py 'static-analysis 4/4' 41f949 \
)
curl \
    --location \
    --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" \
    $zip_path > archive.zip
unzip archive.zip

# Extract the file we want
cp FILE/YOU/WANT $oldpwd

# Go back to where we were
cd $oldpwd
```

Ideally, the code above will be folded into a single Python script that takes 5 inputs all in one place, and produces 1 output: `(token, API URL, job name, commit sha, artefact path) -> artefact file`. Edits welcome. For now, I've used shell as well as Python.

Also ideally, somebody will try out the code above and leave a comment whether they get it to work. I might test it myself. But not today.

Answer (score 2):

This is something you can pass by file.

Create new variable in building job:

```
 variables:
     CONFIG: "anyname"
```

then in script do export/copy to the file, for example:

```
- echo $BUILD_VERSION > $CI_PROJECT_DIR/$CONFIG
```

add paths in artifacts:

```
artifacts:
   paths:
   - $CONFIG
```

then in deploy job

```
variables:
     CONFIG: "anyname"
```

and source it

```
- source $CI_PROJECT_DIR/$CONFIG
```

To make it working, just try to solve passing problems, keep dependencies and to keep artifacts just use "needs", avoid clearing artifacts within job

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But sadly this doesn't work. I get the same output as shown in the screenshot in my question. It sais "Removing anyname" in line 15 again. And the `deploy` job fails because the file to source does not exist. (Btw, `$CONFIG_VERSION` in the `artifacts.paths` is a typo I guess, right? Nevertheless the pipeline fails with both.)

Comment: Yes, sorry, just was looking at build_version and copied. Okey so if it erase then you need to have "needs" option or start using stages like that: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stages, sourcing is problem solving for most use cases if gitlab pipelines are wide

Comment: Well, I **am** using stages **and** `needs`/`dependencies` already. Can you maybe give an example about what you want to have changed comparing to the `yml` posted in my question at the very end?

Answer (score 1):

Building upon [@esteis's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/473899/esteis) answer which has the correct idea but no working E2E implementation.

The main caveat is that the `downloadPath` attribute of the artifact `node` contains the URL that is a) relative and b) web-based (not accepting header token authorisation). So you actually have to build the request using the job ID that you can get via the API. The following working script (also no pagination support, sadly) uses GraphQL API which requires for you to put a private or project token in the header but it seems that you could replace that with a call to the regular [JSON Jobs API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html) which supports `$CI_JOB_TOKEN` variable. The `jq` filter can be tailored to your needs, this is what worked for me.

```bash
            QUERY="{ project(fullPath: \\\"$[[ inputs.project-name ]]\\\") { jobs { nodes { id name refName commitPath } } } }"

            JOBS_JSON=$(curl "$CI_API_GRAPHQL_URL" \
                --header "Authorization: Bearer <private or project token here>" \
                --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
                --request POST \
                --data "{\"query\": \"$QUERY\"}")

            JOB_ID=$(echo $JOBS_JSON | jq --arg COMMIT "<reference to commit like $CI_COMMIT_SHA>" \
                '.data.project.jobs.nodes[] | select(.name == "<branch name here>" and (.refName | test("merge")) and (.commitPath | contains($COMMIT))) | .id' \
                | sed 's/.*\///' | tr -d '"')

            if [[ -n $VALIDATE_JOB_ID ]]; then
                curl --location "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$(echo $CI_PROJECT_PATH | sed 's/\//%2F/g')/jobs/$VALIDATE_JOB_ID/artifacts" \
                    --header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" \
                    --output artifacts.zip 
                unzip artifacts.zip
            fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue than you. I am still thinking the bets solution, but I had an idea that could work.

The only endpoint that works in my case is
`https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/jobs/<job_id>/artifacts`. As I don't know the `job_id` in the second pipeline I cannot use it, but we could get the id using other endpoint.

`https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/jobs?scope[]=success`

Then you have the list of jobs and maybe it's possible to filter to find the id.

The main problem, you get only the last 20 jobs, but you can get the next pages with the parameter [`page`](https://docs.gitlab.com/16.1/ee/api/rest/index.html#pagination).

Comment: I would love an example of this, I was thinking along the same lines. Yet have no clue how to do this in the .gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: Finding <job_id> in the pipeline is hard or impossible